# How do I setup a permanent redirect from one domain to another?

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, cname

I have a domain, say www.example.com which is redirected to a website built in Google Sites. I don't want different search engines treat example.com as a different site from www.example.com. How do I make a permanent link between the two? My domain is under GoDaddy.

**EDIT**

In Go Daddy, I have forwarding option set to Google site link.

Under CNAME, I have Google provided alias and directions.

Comment: Can you provide more information or at least a clearer explanation of what your current setup is (method of redirect, A/CNAME records, etc)?

Answer (score 5):

1) Do a 301 redirect from one to the other. Here is the code you can place in an .htaccess file in your webroot (change your_domain.com to be your actual domain):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.your_domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your_domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

2) In [Google Webmaster Tools you can set your preferred domain](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=44231) so Google knows which one you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify canonical URLs for pages on your site by putting an HTML `<link>` element with proper information in the page `<head>`.

For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish" />
```

See "[Specify Your Canonical](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)" at the Google Webmaster blog.